# How to compile PHP with zip support on a shared hosting

Tags: php, zip, shared-hosting, pecl

I'm getting zipArchive class not found after I deployed my PHP Application on a shared hosting.

I found the answer of this question but I could not run:

```
pecl instal zip
```

as I get

```
-bash: pecl: command not found
```

How to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Shared hosting offers an "out of the box" package that cannot be modified as it will affect *all* accounts on that server which could number in the tens of thousands. If you want to customize your PHP installation you will need a dedicated server (or something similar).

Comment: Big thanks for your answer.
So, do you have any suggestions for using any zip package to deal with zip files ?